# Instruments application can't open tracetemplate file

Tags: ios, macos, instruments

When I open "Instruments" application and try choose any template for my simulator (Time Profiler or any other) I get "Import Trace" window with all possible tracetemplates files from '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/Resources/templates' directory. Then I choose any one and after it I get alert message 'The document “Time Profiler.tracetemplate” could not be opened.'
But in command line instruments works correct.
How can I find reasons of such behaviour?

Also from console application logs I get:
"appleeventsd(62) deny file-read-metadata /Library"

Comment: I have exactly the same issue.

Anyone?

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this problem since this post was created?

Comment: For newer Xcode and Instruments see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49914412/xcode-9-3-and-update-to-high-sierra-instruments-cant-open-tracetemplate-file/50018425#50018425

Answer (score 4):

Found a solution in the new Apple Developer Forums.

Run this from a terminal:

`sudo chmod a+rwxt /Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.instruments`

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6441 for more info.

Comment: chmod: /Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.instruments: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Removing this folder helped me .

```
/Library/Application Support/Instruments
```