# Xcode 6.3.2: Instruments keep asking for trace template?

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments

I've been trying to use the various Instruments provided in Xcode to check for memory leaks and some lag I get when using my Application.

However, despite looking at several tutorials. I keep getting an error every time I try to use Xcode. When starting the tests, I am greeted by a panel prompting me to pick an instrument.

[image]

After picking the Time Profiler, I hit **Choose**, and am immediately prompted by the following screen:

[image]

This usually isn't what I see in any of the tutorials. And it's also where the problem starts. No matter what I pick, or what Instrument I choose to import data with, I always get the following errors:

[image]

I was told I should reinstall Xcode. So after removing the Application, and reinstalling it, I tried again. Same error.

I've tried looking for solutions online as well. All I found was [this similar SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29914660/instruments-application-cant-open-tracetemplate-file)
, which had no answer to it.

Does anyone know why this is occurring, and what I can do to resolve it?

Comment: Try deleting Instruments' preferences: `defaults delete com.apple.dt.Instruments`. You might also try creating a new user account and seeing if Instruments behaves properly there. If so, then the problem is specific to your account in some way.

Comment: @KenThomases Deleting the Instrument Preferences did not solve the problem. I can try creating a new user account though.

Comment: @KenThomases I have just tried using instruments on another User Account. Same problem. Always opens the same prompt, then says it cannot open the file. I'm getting pretty exasperated.

Answer (score 3):

This might work:

```
sudo chmod a+rwxt /Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.instruments
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal app from application. 
Simply Copy & paste & then press Enter. 
Exit Xcode, Then again launch the instruments with your testing app , this time it should load it then asking for selecting the templates from dialog box.

```
sudo chmod a+rwxt /Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.instruments
```

All d best.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  but I cannot test this. I have since switched computers and no longer have access to the one with the issue. Should I mark as solved?