# Xcode 9.3 and update to High Sierra: Instruments can't open *.tracetemplate files even after full reinstall

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, reinstall

With the last update of Xcode to 9.3 running on High Sierra, I realized that `Instruments` is not working any more.

When I try to open it from inside Xcode using `Open Developer Tool > Instruments`, I can see the template chooser dialog but as soon I pick one, a dialog appears:

```
The document "Allocations.tracetemplate" could not be opened. Instruments cannot open files of this type.
```

`Allocations.tracetemplate` could not be handled because Instruments cannot open files of this type.

This happens with all templates.

I already tried to reinstall Xcode completely. Before I deleted all files like described here: [How to Completely Uninstall Xcode and Clear All Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011062/how-to-completely-uninstall-xcode-and-clear-all-settings)

I also tried to use 
sudo chmod a+rwxt /Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.instruments
([Xcode 6.3.2: Instruments keep asking for trace template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30882233/xcode-6-3-2-instruments-keep-asking-for-trace-template#comment49806199_30882233))
but this file does not exist on my computer.

I also installed Xcode 9.4 beta 1 but that didn't solve the issue either.

I also can't find these template files like Allocations.tracetemplate anywhere on my computer.

Any help would be very appreciated ;-)

Comment: Yup this happens for me too after updating Xcode 9.3. Any solution for this?

Comment: Me too. Tried several things, also using Guest Account. Also copied one of the templates from within the App to somewhere else.

Comment: For me the issue was gone after updating to High Sierra 10.13.4 :-) The templates are working again :-)

Comment: I've done everything: all the Terminal commands, all the deleting of caches & AppSupport, updated Xcode, updated High Sierra 10.13.5... Instruments won't open any of its own templates

Answer (score 4):

I still had some old Developer Tools on the HD. Removed following things and it worked again:

- ~/Library/Application Support/Instruments
- everything I found in /Developer/ vaguely attached to Instruments
- especially "3.0/Instruments/
- and the old Instruments.app

also `defaults delete com.apple.dt.Instruments` in Terminal

Comment: Thanks! For me the issue is now solved after I upgraded to High Sierra 10.13.4